# get pid of multiple instances of a process in a script and use them

Tags: shell-script, process

Let's say I'm running multiple instances of process `w1` (from source code `while1.c`) in the background (`while1.c` contains an infinite while loop):

```
gcc while1.c -o w1
./w1&
./w1&
./w1&
./w1&
```

Now I want to get the PID of every instance. For that, I am doing this:

```
var=$(/bin/ps r -o pid,cmd|grep "w1"| grep -v "grep"|awk '{print $1}')
```

That will store the PIDs of all instances of `w1` in `$var`.
So, if I do:

```
echo $var
```

It will print out the PIDs of all instances of `w1`.

But I want to access individual PIDs, i.e. something like:

```
echo ${var[0]}
echo ${var[1]}
```

And so on (something like arrays). How can I do that?

PS: `echo ${var[0]}` is printing all PIDs while `echo ${var[1]}` or `echo ${var[2]}` and so on, is printing nothing (i.e. blank lines of output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the PIDs as you start the processes:

```bash
pids=()

./w1 & pids+=( "$!" )
./w1 & pids+=( "$!" )
./w1 & pids+=( "$!" )
./w1 & pids+=( "$!" )
```

(that's assuming a shell with `bash`-compatible array syntax)

Now you have the PIDs in the array `pids` and can access them as `"${pids[0]}"`, `"${pids[1]}"`, etc.

If you are using plain `/bin/sh`:

```sh
set --

./w1 & set -- "$@" "$!"
./w1 & set -- "$@" "$!"
./w1 & set -- "$@" "$!"
./w1 & set -- "$@" "$!"
```

Now you have the PIDs in the list `"$@"` and can access them as `"$1"`, `"$2"`, etc.

The special value `"$!"` will be the PID of the most recently started background command.

Comment: thanks that worked...

Answer (score 1):

If you're running bash, you can use `jobs -l`, which lists background jobs along with their PIDs.  For example, the following will store all the PIDs of jobs matching `./w1` into array `pids`:

```
pids=( $(jobs -l | awk '/\.\/w1/ {print $2}') )
```

In other shells, you could use `ps --ppid $$` to list all the jobs with the current shell as parent:

```
pids=( $(ps --ppid $$ -o pid,cmd -h | awk '/\.\/w1/ {print $1}') )
```

NOTE: AFAIK, this is not portable - it will only work with `ps` from the Linux `procps` package.  Other versions of `ps` don't have the same options.

With FreeBSD's `ps`, you could do something like this (in bash or ksh or some other shell that supports arrays):

```
pids=( $(ps -j | awk -v ppid=$$ '$3==ppid && /\.\/w1/ {print $2}') )
```

If you have `pgrep` available, you could use:

```
pids=( $(pgrep -P $$ w1) )
```

In all variants, I'm checking that the background process matches `./w1` - if you're certain that there's never going to be any other child or background processes of that PPID running, you can skip that test in the `awk` scripts (and only need to output `-o pid` in the second variant's `ps` command).

Comment: ps will work..../w1&
./w1&
./w1&
./w1&
var=( $(/bin/ps r -o pid,cmd|grep "w1"| grep -v "grep"|awk '{print $1}') )...I was missing one set of parenthesis....

Comment: BTW, you never need to pipe grep into awk.  And you never need to do that annoying `ps | grep | grep -v grep | awk` thing.  that's been around forever and it was never needed.  awk alone is enough.

Comment: thanks @cas, I tried first two methods and both worked perfectly. And that pipe thing was indeed annoying, thanks for pointing that out and suggesting a better way.